# Exam question about Partitions

Tags: linux, partition

Which Partition is required in Linux?

- a.     /dev-partition
- b.     /home-partition
- c.     /swap-partition

My answer was .**a** (/dev )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer: none of the above.**

But the question is ill-posed because:

- `/dev` is usually not a partition. In most modern Linux distributions, it's a virtual in-memory filesystem (`tmpfs`) managed by `udev` so that it dynamically reflects the devices that are actually present in the system.

  But you can have a Linux system with a static `/dev` directory and that directory does not need to be its own filesystem (it usually isn't in this case) but instead would be a regular directory off the root filesystem.
- `/swap` doesn't make sense. Linux systems are usually provisioned with swap space (which is usually a partition) but it's not required. And it's certainly not called `/swap`.

As for `/home`, that, like `/dev`, need not be (and often isn't) a separate filesystem.

Anyway, **a** is probably the answer they're looking for even though it's not correct, and it's probably what I would have answered if faced with that question and only those choices. So you will probably be marked right.

Comment: Thank you Celada. I know its a ill-posed question. that is why i came here to ask.

Comment: In fact, making `/dev` a separate filesystem on secondary storage (i.e., disk or equivalent) would be *very tricky*.  Specifically, mounting it would be very tricky — `mount ` *`(what?) `* `/dev` — chicken begets egg begets chicken.  Also, it would be rather pointless, inasmuch as the `/dev` directory tree requires only the amount of disk space that its *directories* consume — a paltry sum, not worth splitting off into a separate filesystem.

Comment: Pretty good point you got there, @G-Man. Makes the original exam question even stupider.

Comment: (It occurred to me that I should have said "a *poultry* sum", thus making a chicken pun.)  :-) ⁠

Comment: @G-Man don't worry, I'm sure you will have other opportunities for chicken puns in the future.

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte, if you edit your question to include the fact that you *know* the exam question is ill-posed, and clarify that you are asking for a proper explanation of these differences, you may get a better response (in terms of votes).